# Finding on fulltext search troubles

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm working with fulltext indexing in SQL Server, but I have the following trouble:

In my indexed column, there are words and numeric codes that I need to find. For example: 069-8987.15

The users will be searching by the literal code, hybrid way or without the special characters, like 069-8987.15 or 069-898715 or 069898715.

I can do that just in the first case.

```
SELECT [Key], [Rank]
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.History, Report, '*069-8987.15*')
```

If I try to use the others, I can't return anything.

How can I fix this? What do I need to do to return the data using the three search ways?

Comment: I assume this is going to be parametrized?

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search ?

Comment: Yes, @scsimon. It will be parametrized.

Comment: Well, @Alex, I've read, but I didn't find my answer there.

Comment: @Gabriel, there is no quick fix to your problem (http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=160598). You can try playing around with stop lists etc. to see if you can get what you want but .... not simple.

Comment: Like I thought @Alex. I couldn't find any article about that specific problem. thanks for helping.